# What is the meaning of identity in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I already referred to Oxford dictionary but I found no meaning to give sense to "identity" (bold in text) in the following text (from a psychological book)

> If practitioners are dealing with someone from a family that has been traumatised, they need to know the relevant details of the critical events that have affected their client. **Identity** to a group that has been traumatised affects both the personal identity of the person and their continuity. Trainees can learn how to gather such information sensitively. Working with shame and self-esteem are also relevant factors for this training.

Any suggestions on what 'identity' means here?

Comment: sorry - without more context I draw a blank, & I'm native Br E.

Comment: Ok, I am adding context to it now.

Comment: ouch. Was that from a native speaker? It might separate out better if you think of it as "Identity, to a group that has been traumatised, affects…" but it's still not great. "gather these such information" really hurts, though - that's not good English.

Comment: I have no idea if the author was native, but the text obviously didn't look like a native one.

Comment: I struggle to extract the intended meaning even if I reduce it to only the basic elements… Identity [to group] affects 2 things, identity (again) & continuity (…of what?)

Comment: "Identity **of** a group" makes more sense.

Comment: @StoneyB yeah you're right. I just corrected the sentence by removing _these_ before _such_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Identity to a group" is not a meaningful noun phrase.  "Identity to a group that has been traumatised" sounds like it's supposed to be a general version of "[being part of] a family that has been traumatised". Maybe the author is referring to something like [collective identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_identity).

This correct sentence might be close to what the author meant:

> **Being part of** a group that has been traumatised affects both the personal identity of the person and their continuity.

If we take the choice of "identity" seriously, maybe this version is better:

> **Identifying with** a group that has been traumatised affects both the personal identity of the person and their continuity.

I general, I think this is a poorly-written sentence. It's too wordy and the rest of the grammar is questionable. Here's how I would write it, assuming my understanding is correct:

> Being part of a traumatised group affects both a person's identity and their sense of continuity.

Or, if the person is no longer part of the group:

> Having been part of a traumatised group affects both a person's identity and their sense of continuity.